# Move control along path

Tags: c#, wpf, transformation

I want to move a control along a path in WPF with a transformation. The movement should be smooth and the path is like a sine curve. Currently no idea how to start...

-sa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the [Path Animations Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970561.aspx). HTH.